# How to disable or change IntelliJ IDEA splash screen?

Tags: windows, intellij-idea

Can anyone help, how to **disable** or **change** the splash screen of IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: If you are connecting to a machine using RDP, the splash screen display can slow down application startup down greatly.

Comment: Also, if you already have the IDE open and you're loading a file externally, having the splash screen becomes annoying very quickly.

Comment: Also, on Ubuntu 15.10 at least, it stays at the top of the z-order while loading, preventing me from working on at least one monitor.  I thought this behavior disappeared with Windows 98?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

To disable the splash screen add `-Dnosplash=true` in Help | Edit Custom VM Options or `nosplash=true` in Help | Edit Custom Properties.

It can be also disabled by running with `nosplash` command line option. For example, `idea.exe nosplash` (on Windows).

You can modify the menu/desktop shortcut to run with this parameter automatically.
There is also a [feature request to make it a setting](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-72664), feel free to vote.

In case you want to change the image, it's loaded from this file:
`<IDEA_DIR>\lib\resources.jar\idea_logo.png`.

Comment: Example on Linux : `~/Softwares/idea-IU-171.4249.39/bin/idea.sh nosplash&`

Comment: Or if you're on Linux/Gnome you can edit your application/desktop shortcut file (if you have one):


    `~/.local/share/applications/jetbrains-idea.desktop`
    `...`
    `Exec="/path/to/idea/bin/idea.sh" "nosplash" %f`

Comment: In recent versions (e.g. 2021.1) you can use "Help > Edit Custom VM Options ..." and add `-Dnosplash=true` there.

Comment: For changing the splash screen in Pycharm and Clion u have to look for 'pycharm.jar' or 'clion.jar' u can find correspondent splash.png inside that .jar file, sometimes the it may be inside 'artworks' folder .

Comment: On linux, if you want to use the "diff" command with "nosplash", try: `idea -Dnosplash=true diff <full path 1> <full path 2>`

Answer (score 1):

My solution is for PhpStorm but it will be the same on other JetBrains IDEs.

1. Open the `phpstorm.vmoptions` (`phpstorm64.vmoptions` on 64bit systems) file that is in your IDE `bin` directory.
2. Add a `-nosplash` line  at the end of the file.

Splash screen will remain, but won't be on the top.

**Update**

Doesn't work in PhpStorm 2017.2

```
Unrecognized option: -nosplash
```

Comment: May be i'm late but just adding in case it helps someone in future.
Please try "nosplash" without "-" and obviously without quotes

Comment: In my case adding `-Dnosplash=true` to the file worked (in my case the file was `~/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2023.3/idea.vmoptions`)