# Does anyone know how to change the PyCharm splash screen?

Tags: pycharm

I'm trying to customize the PyCharm splash screen, and with resource hacker I'm able to modify the initial splash screen that the pycharm.exe/pycharm64.exe throws up, but that disappears when the loading bar starts and the original splash screen is there again.

Ripped open pycharm.jar with WinRAR and tried replacing:

```
pycharm_core_about@2x.png
pycharm_core_logo@2x.png
pycharm_core_about.png
pycharm_core_logo.png
```

I'm at a loss, and I really don't feel like giving up at this point. I realize this isn't a serious issue, but it's killing me that I don't understand where the image is being stored and how it's being rendered.

Edit: To clarify, I am not trying to re-brand the software. I don't have to get rid of all the obscure places their logo shows up, I really just want a more aesthetically pleasing splash screen. I made a really cool colorization of an image from a cloud chamber (I'm a physics grad student), and wanted to put that in. (Image, if you're interested: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdMW5.png)

Comment: Sounds like you are hacking it to use/sell as your own to avoid licensing. You simply should not do this.

Comment: Noooo sir. Just don't like their splash screen. This is for nerd fun, not for profiit. I'm using PyCharm Community edition; anyone can get that for free. I just want to customize it.

I do this with just about every piece of software I can get my hands on. changed the Alt-Ctrl-Del screen background in Windows, swapped the LiClipse splash screen when I was using that as my IDE, etc.

Comment: Nice image but I don't think you should do this either regardless of your motive as it violates your license agreement. I also have a problem with the splash screen because it pops to the foreground regardless of what else I have going on and is hard to dismiss.  Clicking on it doesn't work unless I first maximize a different window which really interferes with anything else I might be doing. It is as if the designer thought that I'm not supposed to do anything else while waiting for the very long time it takes Pycharm to load.

Comment: This doesn't violate the license agreement. o.O

Answer (score 1):

see here: [How to disable or change IntelliJ IDEA splash screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9915469/how-to-disable-or-change-intellij-idea-splash-screen)

I was looking for disabling it, which worked for me. Did not try to change it though.

Answer (score 0):

PyCharm

- lib/pycharm.jar/pycharm_logo.png
- lib/pycharm.jar/pycharm_logo@2x.png

Comment: Please elaborate. I think this is actually an answer, but that is not obvious.

Comment: Doesn't the question explicitly state that I've tried that? Unless something has changed in the latest versions of PyCharm...